# Different Enter and mouse click event

Tags: java, swing, button, awt, keylistener

i have a button that call a method, in this method it call another method to connect to the DB and return results, if results positive, change the labels and make a button ENABLED, and if the results is negative, the Button still disabled

the problem is, i have set in the TF a keytyped event, if someone type something new in it, disable the btnEditar:

```
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                  
                    btnEditar.setEnabled(false);
                    btnDeletar.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

i dont want this event "capture" the enter to disable the button
there is a way to do that or i have to think i another logic way?

Comment: are you asking that you want on pressing enter it does not disabled the button?

Comment: just use document listener it is much easier than `keyevent` and also get notified when value inserted, changed and deleted. for e.g. you can call an method inside each abstract method of listener like `updateTF() { //check if the textfield contains character or not if(document.getLength()>0) tf.setEnabled(true); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there are other ways to do this besides using a `KeyListener`. I will respond to your original attempt below. A `KeyListener` is a functional and easy tool to use for this job.

Use `keyPressed` instead of `keyTyped`, and then you'll have a valid key code that you can use to ignore enter presses:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { // not keyTyped!
    if (e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        btnEditar.setEnabled(false);
        btnDeletar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

If you insist on using `keyTyped` for some reason, [you won't have a key code available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED), but you can cover most cases by checking the character for a newline or carriage return:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyChar() != 13 && e.getKeyChar() != 10) {
        btnEditar.setEnabled(false);
        btnDeletar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: MAN, worked fine, you are the best, thank you so much, and the explanation why!!! i think i will never do this """mistake""" again :)!

Comment: Don't use magic numbers (13, 10). And as I mentioned in my answer these events are not even generated when you use a DocumentListener so there is no need to use code that excludes certain events.

Comment: Agreed on the "don't use magic numbers" point. Just to be clear, if you do continue using a `KeyListener`, I recommend using `keyPressed` with `VK_ENTER`, as the key code is not subject to locale-specific character encoding.

Comment: `It's clean, precise, straightforward` - I would disagree. The requirement (as I understand it) is to know when text changes in the Document. Adding exclusion logic is not straightforward. First you need to know which key events to exclude. Also, what happens when you start removing characters from the text field? Normally the button would be re-enabled. This is not done easily with this approach as again you need to listen for specific key strokes (the backspace and delete buttons, for example).

Comment: The same caveats hold for `DocumentListener`. First, you need to know that DocumentListener happens to ignore the specific key events you are trying to ignore. Second, the OP's *actual* requirement is that "the button is disabled if the user types something new", in which case *neither* of our proposed solutions really addresses that, and the logic is independent of the use of KeyListener or DocumentListener. To do *that* you'd want to store the value on submit, then any time the text is modified, disable the button if it does not equal that value. *That* is how you handle removes/deletes/etc.

Comment: And in that case the difference between KeyListener and DocumentListener becomes even *more* trivial, as you'd now only looking for a notification that something may have changed, doesn't matter what the nature of the change is.

Comment: Also, re: "This is not done easily with this approach as again you need to listen for specific key strokes (the backspace and delete buttons, for example)." The OP's requirements, the way I read them, is if you remove characters, you still modify the text, and the button still needs to be disabled -- which is taken care of by the case in my example. If you mean that "returning to the original text should re-enable the button" well, like I just described, that's logic beyond what a KeyListener or DocumentListener does. :)

Comment: `The same caveats hold for DocumentListener....` - No, because we are not concerned with KeyEvents. We are concerned with text. A more abstract API is generally better and easier to work with. The separated API to handle insert/remove gives you flexibility to do whatever you want. I did not provide an implementation for the OPs requirement because frankly they are not clear. I introduced the OP to an API that is easier to work with. People should learn both approaches before making a decision.

Comment: +1 for a clear response. Still, as I said, *if* the OP's [unfortunately vague] requirements have to do with the text being changed from its initial value, a comparison between the current value and initial value requires only notification that something may have changed. You could override two DocumentListener events (insert+remove) to signal that (but you would get semantically meaningful notifications), or one KeyListener event (but you would get notifications even if no change took place). In fact, what we'd *really* want is a simple "content changed" event, which neither listener provides.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DocumentListener to listen for changes to the text in the Document. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: While there are certainly reasonable uses for a `DocumentListener`, and while it would get the job done here, this answer is misleading without an explanation of why. It also does not address the OP's specific problem -- the use of a `KeyListener` itself does not prevent the detection of enter presses.

Comment: @JasonC,  A DocumentLstener should be used instead of a KeyListener to listen for changes in a Document. I also know that pressing the Enter key does not generate a Document event so it should not be a concern.

Comment: @user2582318, it may work, but it is NOT the best way to solve the problem. You should not use a KeyListener when using Swing. Swing has better API's to use.

Comment: @camickr It's clean, precise, straightforward, and works in the OP's specific situation. A `DocumentListener` would be a good solution as well to implicitly avoid enter presses. There are many reasons to use a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener` in various situations; but "should" and "it's better" are not on that list of reasons. One way to improve your answer would be to point out how to make the OP's attempt work, in the way he was attempting, and *also* suggest the use of a `DocumentListener` as an alternative, describing the advantages. :)

Comment: @JasonC, `One way to improve your answer would be to point out how to make the OP's attempt work, in the way he was attempting` - I am not going to promote old programming practices. Swing has evolved and has better API's. The DocumnentListener is the "better" solution for the reasons I have already outlined. Unfortunately most people stick with the original solution because they only need to change one or two lines of code.

Comment: I may have missed your outlined reasons, but they should be provided in your answer so that others may benefit.